# How to change route of omniauth from /auth/:provider to /myapp/auth/:provider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

How can I change the route that triggers omniauth from using /auth/:provider to /myapp/auth/:provider ?

I don't want to redirect either, because my server will send anything that's not in /myapp/ to the wrong place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change it via `:setup` option

Source: https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/blob/e9978e377f1ac2b7271e5a8486dfe103a1c1d48d/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb#L304-L307

Comment: Thanks! More specifically, I had to add this to my provider: path_prefix: "/myapp/auth"

Comment: the line have change to https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb#L296

Comment: New line update over here: https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb#L356

Answer (score 12):

Here is how I did this in the **config.ru** file. I my case, my provider is [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas).

```
use OmniAuth::Builder do
  configure do |config|
      config.path_prefix = '/my-app-path/auth'
  end
  provider :cas,  CAS::OPTIONS 
end
```

Note that `CAS::OPTIONS` is an array with CAS configuration for `omniauth::cas`.
This seems to work fine. 
I think you will have to change the omniauth callback too : `/auth/:provider/callback` should be prefixed to `/my-app-path/auth/:provider/callback`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following option in your initializer:

```
option :request_path, 'https://yourdomain.com/auth/yourprovider/callback'
```

Restart you app server and try!