# Change Omniauth authorization URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I'm using Omniauth with Devise using the `google_oauth2` strategy.
It works well, but now I'd like to change the authorize path with something of my choice.

Actually it's `http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2` while I'd like a much simpler `http://localhost:3000/login` since it's simple to remember.

It would not raise any error since I've disabled the Devise database authenticable (the only way to login is through a google account).

How can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm still very much learning Rails myself so not confident in this answer (hence leaving it as a comment), but could you use `match`? `match "users/auth/google_oauth2" => "login#index"` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can see how to change url prefix here [How to change route of omniauth from /auth/:provider to /myapp/auth/:provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033413/how-to-change-route-of-omniauth-from-auth-provider-to-myapp-auth-provider)
So it is almost what you need.