# How to change /auth/:provider path by omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

To remove controller's name I wrote in routes.rb like this.

```
get "/:user_id/:id", :to => "words#show", :as => :short_user_word
```

It worked fine, but when I tried to use the path "/auth/:provider/" from omniauth,
the first route overwrite omniauth's path.

Omniauth callback url works with following route.

```
get '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'
```

I want to also set the path "/auth/:provider/", but I don't know how to write right side of this.

I've read this question and answer, but I couldn't find how to use :setup option.

[How to change route of omniauth from /auth/:provider to /myapp/auth/:provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033413/how-to-change-route-of-omniauth-from-auth-provider-to-myapp-auth-provider)

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: I found what was wrong. I must have used '/users/auth/:provider' path if I use omni_auth with devise.

Answer (score -2):

Your routes order must be like below

```
get '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'
get "/:user_id/:id", :to => "words#show", :as => :short_user_word
```

So first if find /auth/:provider it pick this route otherwise if fetch your normal route